# spring boot docker crashes a whole image on live reload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

The problem is when spring boot app gets triggered by live reload. Then it usually crashes a whole docker image. it's not on every live reload happens, but it happens very often.
`docker-compose.yml`

```html
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: youtube-spring-boot-image
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=posts
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

`application.yml`

```html
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      poll-interval: 2s
      quiet-period: 1s
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        one-indexed-parameters: true
        max-page-size: 50

  profiles:
    active: dev
---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  devtools:
    remote:
      secret: "mysecret"
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/posts
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: 'true'
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: 'true'
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: 'true'
```

`ChannelController.java`

```html
package com.project.youtube.channel;


import com.project.youtube.channel.dto.body.CreateChannelDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/channels")
public class ChannelController {

    @Autowired
    ChannelServiceInterface channelService;

    @PostMapping
    Channel createChannel(@Valid @RequestBody CreateChannelDTO channel){
        return channelService.saveChannel(channel);
    }

    @GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
    Channel findById(@PathVariable UUID id){
        return channelService.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }

    @GetMapping("/findByName/{name}")
    Channel findByName(@PathVariable String name){
        return channelService.findByName(name).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

`ChannelService.java`

```html
package com.project.youtube.channel;

import com.project.youtube.channel.dto.body.CreateChannelDTO;
import com.project.youtube.common.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.project.youtube.user.User;
import com.project.youtube.user.UserServiceInterface;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class ChannelService implements ChannelServiceInterface {

    @Autowired
    ChannelRepository channelRepository;

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    UserServiceInterface userService;

    @Override
    public Page<Channel> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Channel saveChannel(CreateChannelDTO channel) {
        Channel channelEntity = modelMapper.map(channel, Channel.class);
        User user = userService.findById(channel.getUser()).orElseThrow();
        System.out.println(user);
        if(user.getChannel() != null){
            throw new BadRequestException("User already has a channel");
        }
        channelEntity.setUser(user);

        return channelRepository.save(channelEntity);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Channel> findById(UUID id) {
        return channelRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Channel> findByName(String name) {
        return channelRepository.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

error

```html
2022-10-22 15:07:20.441  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.project.youtube.YoutubeApplication   : Starting YoutubeApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.4.1 on 369da96882ed with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
2022-10-22 15:07:20.441  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.project.youtube.YoutubeApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-10-22 15:07:20.568  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-22 15:07:20.577  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-22 15:07:20.620  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-22 15:07:20.621  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-22 15:07:20.621  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-10-22 15:07:20.626  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-22 15:07:20.626  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 183 ms
2022-10-22 15:07:20.649  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.d.a.RemoteDevToolsAutoConfiguration : Listening for remote restart updates on /.~~spring-boot!~/restart
2022-10-22 15:07:20.660  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-22 15:07:20.662  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Starting...
2022-10-22 15:07:20.670  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Start completed.
2022-10-22 15:07:20.671  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-10-22 15:07:20.751  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-10-22 15:07:20.751  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-22 15:07:20.756  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.f
actory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'channelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'channelService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.youtube.channel.ChannelServiceInterface' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-10-22 15:07:20.756  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-22 15:07:20.757  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-10-22 15:07:20.758  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Shutdown completed.
2022-10-22 15:07:20.758  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-10-22 15:07:20.764  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-22 15:07:20.780 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field channelService in com.project.youtube.channel.ChannelController required a bean of type 'com.project.youtube.channel.ChannelServiceInterface' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.youtube.channel.ChannelServiceInterface' in your configuration.


Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=6967925842, committed=410233938
-                 Java Heap (reserved=6144655360, committed=155189248)
                            (mmap: reserved=6144655360, committed=155189248)

-                     Class (reserved=98438868, committed=12259028)
                            (classes #16438)
                            (  instance classes #15272, array classes #1166)
                            (malloc=1969876 #37911)
                            (mmap: reserved=96468992, committed=10289152)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=67108864, committed=63832064)
                            (    used=63492728)
                            (    waste=339336 =0.53%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=96468992, committed=10289152)
                            (    used=9920144)
                            (    waste=369008 =3.59%)

-                    Thread (reserved=28445208, committed=1350168)
                            (thread #28)
                            (stack: reserved=28364800, committed=1269760)
                            (malloc=45944 #196)
                            (arena=34464 #60)

-                      Code (reserved=255452840, committed=27645608)
                            (malloc=1820328 #9753)
                            (mmap: reserved=253632512, committed=25825280)

-                        GC (reserved=284467544, committed=62202200)
                            (malloc=22499672 #9236)
                            (mmap: reserved=261967872, committed=39702528)

-                  Compiler (reserved=44841728, committed=44841728)
                            (malloc=47848 #1198)
                            (arena=44793880 #27)

-                     JVMCI (reserved=104, committed=104)
                            (malloc=104 #7)

-                  Internal (reserved=452902, committed=452902)
                            (malloc=416038 #11608)
                            (mmap: reserved=36864, committed=36864)

-                    Symbol (reserved=16537712, committed=16537712)
                            (malloc=15678152 #395104)
                            (arena=859560 #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=7534776, committed=7534776)
                            (malloc=7288 #101)
                            (tracking overhead=7527488)

-        Shared class space (reserved=12582912, committed=10981376)
                            (mmap: reserved=12582912, committed=10981376)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=6492528, committed=6492528)
                            (malloc=6492528)

-                   Tracing (reserved=33121, committed=33121)
                            (malloc=393 #10)
                            (arena=32728 #1)
```

If I wanna start my app first I run `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -fn` to create spring boot image and then `docker-compose up`. It starts perfectly fine, it crashes only when live reload is triggered. Also I have created run configuration in intellij (without it live reload is not working).
[image]

So if anyone knows how to deal with it, please help, cause this became very frustrating. I actually do not know what is wrong here. This is the only docker setup, that I able to find, that works with live reload, if someone knows better docker setup, that works with live reload please share with me.
github https://github.com/EivydasV/spring-youtube

Comment: Hi @Eivydas Vickus. From posted log seems that there is an issue with initializing `channelController` because of missing dependency  `ChannelServiceInterface`. Can you add add controller and service to description? Have you tried to run your app from IDEA?

Comment: 2 hints beside the already given "solution/hin": If your application will not be extended or become a lib for others, then remove the interfaces. They are resource and time consuming + giving complexity to the files/code.

The other one is that you should use constructor injection and replace @AutoWired by that.

Comment: @artiomi I do not think that's a problem, because for example when it crashes like this, I can just restart docker containers and the app starts successfully (without editing the code), so if something is wrong in my code it should not start no matter what. Also if I run my app without docker with IDEA it starts successfully. I updated my post and even added github link.

Comment: @LenglBoy your tips may be good, but it does not explain why my app is not working with docker

Comment: @EivydasVickus that's why it is added as a comment and not as solution. Beside artiomi already gave you some hint. Bean implementation/Bean can not be found.

Comment: @LenglBoy yeah but if I get `Bean implementation/Bean can not be found`  my app should not start no matter what, but now I just restart docker containers and it works again without any code edit, it only crashes like this when IntelliJ triggers live reload